# How to preselect items in a kendo-multiselect

Tags: kendo-multiselect

I am trying to set default or pre select values in a kendo multiselect which data source is an array.
This is my multiselect:

```
<kendo-multiselect
         v-model="JobStatusFilter" 
         id="ddlstatusField"
         ref="jobStatusSelect"
         :auto-bind="true"
         :data-source="JobStatusFilterDatas"
         :value-primitive="false"
         :auto-width="true"
         :height="800">
      </kendo-multiselect>
```

I was trying to set up default values using javascript as shown below:

```
          var multiSelectWidget = $("#ddlstatusField").data("kendoMultiSelect");
          multiSelectWidget.value("Scheduled");
```

But seems like it is not possible to access to the value function.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Ok, will answer my own question. It worked after I added the script below just after kendo multiselect

```
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function () {                                      
    $("#ddlstatusField").getKendoMultiSelect().value(["Scheduled", "InProcess"]);
   });
    </script>
```